# Algorithm to find the nth root of a number using bisectional search?

Tags: python, sorting, math

```
y = float(input('Enter the number that you want to find the square root of: '))
num = y
x = 0
ans = 0

while abs(ans**2 - abs(num)) > 0.0001 and ans <= y:
    ans = (x + y) / 2.0
    if ans**2 < num:
        x = ans
    else:
        y = ans

print('The square root of', num, 'is', ans)
```

I need to convert this into code that allows you to choose the root e.g. right now it does it to 2 root but i want to choose a different one for example 3 (cubed root) or any other number.

Problem is I can't figure it out. Gimme a hand anyone?

Simply, I can't do it.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `ans ** 2` with `ans ** n`?

Comment: You should read about the Newton-Raphson method.  This uses the derivative to estimate (very quickly) equations like this.

Comment: contact your teacher.

Answer (score -2):

Quite simply, one would probably utilize the "pow" function as noted in the following reference [Power Function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pow-function/).

As an example, here is a code snippet.

```
while True:
    entry = int(input("Enter a value to be evaluated or '0' to quit: "))
    if entry == 0:
        break
    root = int(input("Enter the root value to be used to evaluate: "))

    exponent = float(1 / float(root))

    print("The evaluated value is: ", pow(entry, exponent))
```

Testing out this code snippet results in the following sample terminal output.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Root$ python3 Root.py 
Enter a value to be evaluated or '0' to quit: 8
Enter the root value to be used to evaluate: 3
The evaluated value is:  2.0
Enter a value to be evaluated or '0' to quit: 10000
Enter the root value to be used to evaluate: 4
The evaluated value is:  10.0
Enter a value to be evaluated or '0' to quit: 27
Enter the root value to be used to evaluate: 2
The evaluated value is:  5.196152422706632
Enter a value to be evaluated or '0' to quit: 0
```

Give that a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  He specifically wanted to use an estimation algorithm.